# Converting XSL-FO to HTML

Tags: c#, html, xslt, xsl-fo

I have set of XSL-FO documents which are used for PDF generation. Also I have a requirement to get the same output data (which are in PDF) exported as an HTML file. Further, I need the HTML to have a similar styles as in PDF.

Is there any way to convert XSL-FO to XHTML using C#?

**NOTE :** I know one option is to use ["RenderX:FO2HTML"](http://services.renderx.com/Content/tools/fo2html.html). But since it's a commercial product, I would like to learn about any other options available and do a comparison before continuing further.

Answer (score 4):

I use the RenderX [fo2html stylesheet](http://www.renderx.com/tools/fo2html.html) a lot, and I recommend it to my customers because it is zero cost.  Thus I have built it into a number of client solutions.  You have to go through the [RenderX online store](http://www.renderx.com/download/shop.html) to get it, but it costs nothing.

Comment: RenderX is no longer free!

Comment: Yes, RenderX XEP is no longer free, but RenderX fo2html.xsl is free.  I'm quoting http://www.renderx.com/download/shop.html where it says "XSL 1.0 to HTML Converter $0".  As I said, I've downloaded it many times, once for each customer, and I've never been charged.

Comment: Ken is correct on this one. (1) There is a free XSL for converting XSL FO to HTML. It's merely a style sheet and can be/has been by others enhanced in many areas. (2) There is an not free output module that utilizes the not free composition engine. This converts the area tree to HTML using information from the composition. There is a big difference in this besides the obvious (not free), the output HTML is nearly 100% fidelity to the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Write or find an XSLT stylesheet which converts XSL-FO into XHTML, modify it if necessary to get the rendering you require? Websearching "XSL-FO to HTML" finds at least one such.

Though this is somewhat backward. Normally the document starts in some semantic markup language (such as XHTML), and a stylesheet converts it into XSL-FO for rendering.

Comment: Thanks keshlam! Is there any such free XSLT templates available? Or is there any articles/guides on writing a XSLT to process XSL-FO?
I have done quite a search on this, but I was unable to find. If you happen to know any resources, would really appreciate if you could point me to them.

Comment: Websearch on the obvious keywords suggested that these may exist. Haven't used them, can't vouch for them, so I think you need to do your own research from here.