# The element 'xsl:stylesheet' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema

Tags: c++, xsl-fo, msxml

I'm trying to convert an XSL-FO document to HTML using the "fo2html.xsl" file from RenderX.  That was the suggestion from this StackOverflow post:
[Converting XSL-FO to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594741/converting-xsl-fo-to-html)

I'm using the `load()` method, and it works on everything up until loading the "fo2html.xsl" file.

```
            hr = pXMLDoc->load(vSource, &vbResult);
```

The `IXMLDOMParseError` object is telling me that it's line 24 of the XML that is the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY anchor "<xsl:apply-templates select='@id' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'/>">
  <!ENTITY add-style "<xsl:call-template name='add-style-attribute' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'/>">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
```

Line 24 is the last line of the above XML.  The error source is returning `exclude-result-prefixes="fo">`, and the reason is:

```
The element 'xsl:stylesheet' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema
```

I've tried `pDoc2->put_resolveExternals(VARIANT_TRUE);` and `pDoc2->setProperty(L"ProhibitDTD", v);`, but neither changed anything.

What do I need to do to load "fo2html.xsl" using MSXML?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute, it is the `xsl;stylesheet` declaration, but the error only comes at the close of the element. If you close the element on the next line instead of with the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute, the error will show on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding an XML declaration (see https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) that indicates that the document is standalone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
```

Alternatively, you might need to expand the entities yourself and get rid of the DOCTYPE declaration so there's no schema in the file.